# jQuery html() function and &nbsp;

Tags: javascript, jquery, non-breaking-characters

I have a string that contains unicode encoded nonbreaking space. I need to save this string to the hidden HTML element, so another function can read this value.

It looks like `html()` function does some transformation of the string. Example:

```
  var testString = "string with \xa0 non breaking space";
  $(".export-file-buffer").html(testString);
  var receivedString = $(".export-file-buffer").html();
  console.log(testString);
  console.log(receivedString);
```

What I see in console:

```
string with   non breaking space
string with &nbsp; non breaking space
```

Why exactly it's happening? Could you point me to the doc that describes this behavior?

Comment: The [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/html/) say "This method uses the browser's innerHTML property. Some browsers may not return HTML that exactly replicates the HTML source in an original document. For example, Internet Explorer sometimes leaves off the quotes around attribute values if they contain only alphanumeric characters."

Comment: You told the browser to parse it as HTML. It did so. Maybe don't tell it to parse it as html?

Comment: Why store the data in an HTML element at all? That's what's messing things up.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5fbvk06x/ This logic is not specific to jQuery.  Vanilla javascript assigning the html of an Element also behaves in the same way.  Setting the innerHTML of an element is essential the behavior that `html()` is wrapping.  Ref. https://j11y.io/jquery/#v=git&fn=jQuery.fn.html

Comment: @powerbuoy it looks like storing it with `html` function specifically is messing things up. I'm reusing existing function, but it looks like it won't work for my data.

Comment: So is the desire here to be able to store the string and when you read it again to still have the `\xa0`?  Is that the question you are asking?

Comment: @Taplar yes, exactly. I want to store string on web page and be able to read exactly the same string by different JS function.

Comment: Ok, and just to make sure you are aware.  You do realize that when you put a `\x..` reference into a string in javascript, when that javascript is compiled that that string will not have that literal reference in there, and will instead have the single character that that hex code references, right?

Comment: @Taplar I realize it now. Does it mean I should escape characters like this before saving string on a web page so javascript will not replace them?

Comment: It really depends on how you are going to use this data going forward.  If you are going to display it to the end user, you could encode it so they see it.  Otherwise, how important is it that you see the hex value, rather than the system understanding what that hex value is?

Comment: If it doesn't need to be stored between page reloads just use a variable in a scope available to both functions (or create some sort of storage object/class specifically designed for this) or if it needs to be available for the entire session use localStorage

Comment: @Taplar in this scenario it's important to be able to store and retrieve exactly the same string. `\x..` to `nbsp` transformation is considered as error. After reading comments I realized that it's better to write new function specifically for my case to avoid storing any information on a web page. TY!

Comment: someone is having a downvote partay

Comment: I modified my earlier answer below to show that you can use `data()` if you want to avoid the &nbsp conversion, and also wrote a small conversion script to convert the ascii character back into the \x format. @Tamara

Answer (score 0):

Rather than making it displayable, if you just need to store a reference to it on an element you can use the `data()` method.

```js
var testString = "string with \xa0 non breaking space";
var $target = $('#target');

$target.data('rawData', testString);

console.log($target.data('rawData'));

var fromData = $target.data('rawData');

console.log(
  fromData.split('').map(function(character){
    if (character < ' ' || character > '~' ) {
      return '\\x'+ character.charCodeAt(0).toString(16);
    } else {
      return character;
    }
  }).join('')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="target"></div>
```

As you can see, the value is not converted to `&nbsp;`.  The reason for this is that when jQuery sets a value on an Element with `data()` it does not put it directly on the element.  Rather, it stores the value in an internal cache and associates the value to the element.  Since the value is only in javascript memory, the browser does not convert it.

The value still prints out in the console not as `\xa0` because that hex character code reference is not a visible character code on the ascii chart.  I included a little script that encodes the characters on the ascii chart before space and after the tilde.

Comment: Perhaps provide a solution?

Comment: Ok fair enough.

Answer (score -1):

There are multiple ways of keeping string that can be shared on a html page.

1. Using input type="hidden". Here you can simply keep value by $(".export-file-buffer").val(testString) just like you did for html
2. (less recommended) Using a global variable/ keeping on window. 
   *window.export-file-buffer = testString*
   and retrieve later calling *window.export-file-buffer*